# Run query with different filters based on day of week PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

Trying to run the same view with different date filters depending on which day I'm running it. If I run the query on a Fri, Sat, Sun, or Mon then the dates should be filtered on Tues-Thurs. If I run the query on Tues, Wed, Thurs then the dates should be filtered on Fri-Mon. Those are the only two scenarios. I'm using PostgreSQL.

The view itself is pretty simple otherwise:

```
select * from tbl_1
where date between ____ and _____
```

I do have a dates table that I can join to. I've tried something like:

```
(select date
,case when day_of_week_iso IN(2, 3, 4) THEN 1 ElSE 4 END as "day"
from tbl.date
where date = current_date
) dates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extract(dow from current_date)` which gives current day of week (Sunday is 0), see [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html).

```
select *
from tbl_1
where case extract(dow from current_date)
    when 2 then date between current_date- 4 and current_date- 1
    when 3 then date between current_date- 5 and current_date- 2
    when 4 then date between current_date- 6 and current_date- 3
    when 5 then date between current_date- 3 and current_date- 1
    when 6 then date between current_date- 4 and current_date- 2
    when 0 then date between current_date- 5 and current_date- 3
    when 1 then date between current_date- 6 and current_date- 4
    end;
```

You could use your own function(s) to shorten the code, but the use of `case` with all cases is simpler and probably faster.